# How to stop PdfDocument.writeTo() function upon user's request

Tags: android, pdf, pdfdocument

I am using the following code to create a PDF document using Android `PdfDocument` and write to a file. The `createDocument()` function is called in a non-Ui thread (using `AsyncTask`), and the user can request to stop this operation (facilitated through `shouldStop()`).

When there are many pages, `doc.writeTo(out)` takes a considerable amount of time to complete. I want to be able to cancel `doc.writeTo` operation as well, depending on whether the user has requested to stop. Note, per Android [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.java;l=175;drc=19294005eee57bdf12437351ef50206dc093e2f0;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=PdfDocument&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) `doc.writeTo` calls [this](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.cpp#138) native function.

Is there anyway to facilitate stopping `doc.writeTo` while it is being executed?

```
void createDocument() {
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.getSize(); i++) {
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(100, 100, i + 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = doc.startPage(pageInfo);
        // draw something on page
        doc.finishPage(page);
        if (shouldStop()) return;   // shouldStop() will return true if user has requested from another thread to cancel creating the doc
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    doc.writeTo(out);  // --->>> PROBLEMATIC TIME CONSUMING LINE, want to stop writing if user requests
    doc.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off-  please don't use AsyncTask for time consuming functions.  Use a Thread.  AsyncTask doesn't work well for time consuming functions, because they execute round robin on a single thread.  In fact, that's why AsyncTask is deprecated and shouldn't be used at all anymore.

Secondly, no there isn't a way to stop it safely.  You could kill whatever thread it's on, but with an AsyncTask that would break all AsyncTasks in the app, and in any case it could cause unknown errors or corruption on disk.  Instead, do it in a separate thread in the background and you shouldn't need to worry about how long it takes because you don't have to wait for it to finish.